# What is the minimum space needed for Ubuntu 16.04LTS 32bit? Do I need a linux swap also?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, swap

I am severely limited on my main hdd, as /dev/sda1 (windows 7) is 59.51gib with a 2gib linux swap, and a 13gib /dev/sda2 ext4 where I had an installation of Arch 32. Is it possible install Ubuntu 16.04lts 32 in same partition?
Do I still need the 2g swap to run Ubuntu? Thanks David

Comment: How much memory (RAM) do you have? That will have a big effect on how much swap you need. Also, what is the machine used for: LibreOffice, games, developing...?

Comment: The amount of space required will vary on what you plan to do with it.  You haven't said if desktop/server either..  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements gives minimums (it was increased regards disk space for Ubuntu Desktop 17.04 & switch to GNOME), but your use-case will dictate space required for your system.  You are aware 16.04 reaches EOL in April-2021?  (ie. 18.04 *flavors* make more sense to me on i386 systems)

Comment: Keep in mind 16.04 goes EOL in April of this year.

Comment: You can swap one OS with another (ie. replace *arch* or any other OS with Ubuntu), but we can't say if swap is necessary for you; it'll depend on your machines resources and the end-use you'll use it for. I still use *i386* hardware (Debian & Ubuntu call all 32-bit i386, which today is i686 actually) and I have swap enabled. My boxes rarely use it, but with 1 & 1.5gb of RAM the performance boost makes it I quite necessary somewhat regularly You'll need to decide on your end-use case.  *Opinion questions (where not enough details is given for specific answer) are off-topic on this site*